# WooCommerce: Force coupon for existing/registered customers

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic, order

I have some specific regular customers for which I have particular coupons, like 10%, 15% etc.
I want the coupon codes to be fixed in their useraccounts so that they do NOT need to enter it during ordering-process.

Is it possible?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a simple plugin if you want to use called Woocommerce Extended Coupon Features Free. This is a freemium plugin but adds enough options to be able to do what you want. Link for the plugin

https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-auto-added-coupons/